# For loop over Data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, function, loops

I have a DF with daily temperature data over a period of ten years. I would like to calculate the daily mean for the ten years, so I get 365 values. I can do it manual as you can see below, but is it possible with a loop or function. My problem is I can´t see how to build this loop or function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import hvplot.pandas

ds = xr.open_dataset('multiyear_final.nc')
ds = ds.rename({'analysed_st':'SST'})

lon=[-52]
lat=[69]
lon1 = [-20]
lat1 = [74]
ds1 = ds.SST.sel(lon=lon, lat=lat, method='nearest')
ds2 = ds.SST.sel(lon=lon1, lat=lat1, method='nearest')

#########################################################
df_time =  ds1.to_dataframe()
result1 = df_time.iloc[[0,365,730,1095,1460,1826,2191,2556,2921,3287]]
res1 = result1['SST'].mean()

result2 = df_time.iloc[[1,366,731,1096,1461,1827,2192,2557,2922,3288]]
res2 = result2['SST'].mean()

result3 = df_time.iloc[[2,367,732,1097,1462,1828,2193,2558,2923,3289]]
res3 = result3['SST'].mean()
```

Comment: Why a loop? It will be a lot slower than what you're doing. Which is rather unclear - you're calculating the mean of 10 days over the last 10 years, not a running average or the yearly average. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can use pandas.date_range to generate evenly spaced dates, eg `pd.date_range('2013-01-01', periods=10, freq='Y')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I´m building a baseline with the avg. of the sea surface temperature for ten years.

Answer (score 0):

Your time coordinate looks like it is in days of year since some kind of epoch. To properly do the calculation you want to be doing you would have to convert that time coordinate to day of year (0-365) and save it.

Naively you could take the remainder of a division by 365, however that would not account for leap years, so it would be preferable to do a better conversion. How to do that I can't tell you since I don't have access to your data. So let's just go with my naive approach.

Then you just group by the day of year and get the mean per group:

```
ds["doy"] = ds.time % 365
long_term_avg = ds.groupby("doy").mean()
```

(I have not tested this code since you didn't provide a minimal example, but it should give you pointers in the right direction.)